# Wrong value returned from mysql float

Tags: mysql, precision

I have a table with high precision value, stored as `Float`. When I query the table for that value it returns rounded off value, rounded to 1st digit. But when I run the below query I am getting the value that I have stored,

```
SELECT MY_FLOAT_COL*1 FROM MY_TABLE;
```

What's going on inside Mysql?

Comment: you mean running this: `SELECT MY_FLOAT_COL FROM MY_TABLE` returns rounded float val? without multiplication

Comment: That's just how it is with floats.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili yes...

Comment: @Strawberry Thats how means "how".. Is it that the float is always rounded to 1 digit? If so what is the type when I multiply it by 1? What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store **exact** values, you'd use the [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) data types.

By manual of [`FLOAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html):

> The `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` types represent *approximate numeric* data values. MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values

The thing to mention here is ***approximation***.

You can read more on floats here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: I am sure its notthe problem with storing, since i am able to get the proper value as mentioned... i would like to understand what exactly is the problem/behaviour with retrieval...

Comment: yes data type is problem. you can change to decimal and you'll see the problem is gone

Comment: if you read the links I've mentioned you will get the whole idea and difference between those types