# Whats going on with Mysql float?

Tags: mysql, precision

This is somewhat related to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39011776/2046462). I understand the float is not suggested for high precision. But I don't exactly get what's going on with *FLOAT* after going through the below results,

**Observation 1**

The value returned by the below 2 queries returns different results,

```
SELECT MY_FLOAT_COL FROM MY_TABLE;

SELECT MY_FLOAT_COL*1 FROM MY_TABLE;
```

The possible explanation is the reference in the above link, which says the float is approximate value and the problem is the datatype.

**Observation 2**

The queries

```
SELECT MY_FLOAT_COL*1 FROM MY_TABLE;

SELECT MY_FLOAT_COL FROM MY_TABLE;
```

returns the same result when I execute using Squirrel SQL(Java), but returns different results when executed through Heidi SQL(Object Pascal) and Python script. So this leads to a conclusion that the problem is with the client.

What exactly is going on with the `Float` datatype of Mysql. I am trying to make sense of above 2 observations.

**Edit:** I care more about my **Observation 2**. I am able to make some sense out of my **Observation 1** but the latter is mysterious as of now.

Comment: Different SQL engines implement some things differently. What is your question?

Comment: All the observations are in same server. My question is, as mentioned trying to make sense of the observation...

Answer (score 3):

When you multiply by `1`, the result is being converted to `DOUBLE`. This has more precision, and as a result you can see the error in the decimal approximation. You can see the same thing by assigning a `FLOAT` column to a `DOUBLE` column.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `my_float_col` float,
  `my_double_col` double
);
INSERT INTO my_table (my_float_col) values (1.2355);
UPDATE my_table SET my_double_col = my_float_col;
SELECT my_float_col, my_double_col, my_float_col * 1 FROM my_table;
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| my_float_col | my_double_col      | my_float_col * 1   |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|       1.2355 | 1.2354999780654907 | 1.2354999780654907 |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I'm not really sure why it's returning `DOUBLE` from the multiplication, because the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html) says:

> If any of the operands of a `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `%` is a real or string value, the precision of the result is the precision of the operand with the maximum precision.

But it's clearly what's happening.

Comment: Barmar, I think the case has been solved with the mystery manual page I unearthed.

Comment: You always do Barmar :p

Comment: Most programming languages evaluate any expression containing `float` as `double` anyway, just as they promote everything to `int` if there is no wider type. I suggest that is what MySQL is doing as well, contrary to its documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the details. But still I am unable to reason my Observation 2

Comment: That may be due to how Java and Pascal round floating point numbers when they display them. I don't program in either language, so I can't speak more authoritatively.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening can be explained with a slight modification to Barmar's answer which I have below:

```
drop table if exists my_table2;
CREATE TABLE `my_table2` (
  `my_float_col` float(18,16), -- FLOAT(M,D)
  `my_double_col` double(18,16)
);
INSERT INTO my_table2 (my_float_col) values (1.2355); -- 1.2354999780654907
UPDATE my_table2 SET my_double_col = my_float_col;
SELECT my_float_col, my_double_col, my_float_col * 1 FROM my_table2;
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| my_float_col       | my_double_col      | my_float_col * 1   |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 1.2354999780654907 | 1.2354999780654907 | 1.2354999780654907 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

The float (column 1) for Barmar is a C float datatype just as mine is. But because he did not specify the precision `(M,D)`, the internal implementation in C still pegs it as a C float, we have the same value, but the fact is lost in Barmar's. It is just that his display width rounds it up. Note the function I created below that can show that.

And check out this humorous MySQL Manual page entitled [FLOAT and DOUBLE Data Type Representation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/floating-point-types.html) and I think it will be very clear to anyone delving into it. Because we would, afterall, be math-heads anyway:

> Let us now take up the story from where the MySQL Reference Manual
>   leaves off.
>
> The following discussion concentrates on the case where no display
>   width and decimals are given. This means that FLOAT is stored as
>   whatever the C type float is and REAL or DOUBLE [PRECISION] is stored
>   as whatever the C type double is. The field length is selected by the
>   MySQL code.

So despite Barmar's first column of output, it was never in there as a `1.2355`, and the above manual page cleverly and humorously describes the head-banging that people have gone through.

Helper fcn if of interest:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS returnFloatFromDec;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION returnFloatFromDec(n DECIMAL(18,16))
returns FLOAT
BEGIN
    DECLARE theRet FLOAT;
    SET theRet=n; -- note that CAST can't take a FLOAT
    return(theRet);
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. But still I am unable to reason my Observation 2.

Comment: It is very clear that the data is stored as a C float and it is a display issue. The above referenced link spells it out