# Why and how Mysql float works fine only with Java?

Tags: java, python, mysql, floating-point

I am trying to execute the below queries with different languages and different DB clients.

```
SELECT MY_FLOAT_COL*1 FROM MY_TABLE;

SELECT MY_FLOAT_COL FROM MY_TABLE;
```

As per my observation the first query returns deviated results in Python and DB clients such as Heidi SQL, as reasoned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39048275/2046462). But a Java code or DB Client using JDBC connection(Squirrel) returns same results for the above mentioned query. What magic that Java does, how can I make that magic work with other languages/clients?

**Note:**This is actually a subset of my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047486/whats-going-on-with-mysql-float). The initial question diverts user from providing the complete answer. I want this question to be answered more specifically.

Comment: This sounds like it might be more a driver issue.

Comment: Driver issue with all the languages other than Java..?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned on the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047486/whats-going-on-with-mysql-float/39048275#39048275) multiply the `MY_FLOAT_COL*1` change the precision level because it is converted to `DOUBLE`.

When you retrieve data from a client, if you treat it as a number you convert it to the kind of type used by the client. So the conversion happens twice.

In java I suppose that you convert it back to `float`. If you retrieve it as a `BigDecimal` (or as a `String`) you can see the exact representation used internally by the database.

---

Note that the difference between java and python is due to the internal representation of `float` that is not the same in java and in python. `float` in python should be similar to `double` in java.

Comment: Irrespective as whatever type I get, I get the same result. I don't think that matters.

Comment: Try to post your java and python code. So we can see differences.